# How to make work a computed field with "store=True" when I am using fields from other model?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10

I have the `pos_order_total` field in the contact tree view. It is calculated perfecly if `store=False`, but if `store=True` it is not calculated if I make some POS order. So how can I make this work with `store=True`

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    pos_order_total = fields.Monetary(
        string='POS Order Total',
        compute='_compute_pos_order_total',
        store=True)

    def _compute_pos_order_total(self):
        Order = self.env['pos.order']
        for partner in self:
            total = 0.0
            domain = [('partner_id', '=', partner.id)]
            for o in Order.search(domain):
                total += o.amount_total
            partner.pos_order_total = total
```

Comment: Why would you like to store it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Theory

Take a look at the Odoo Documentatio for [**computed fields**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields)

```
total = fields.Float(compute='_compute_total')

@api.multi
@api.depends('value', 'tax')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        record.total = record.value + record.value * record.tax
```

As you can see you need to add the dependencies to trigger the computed method and update the value. The fields `value` and `tax` are in the same model in this case. So if you are using fields from the same model or related to that model, the `store=True` is going to work well . So you should connect the fields by relations if it is possible.

### Solution

In your case you need to create an `one2many` field to relate the tables. Check if the following code works for you:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    pos_order_total = fields.Float(
        string='POS Order Total',
        compute='_compute_pos_order_total',
        store=True
    )

    pos_order_ids = fields.One2many(
        string=u'POS Orders',
        comodel_name='pos.order',
        inverse_name='partner_id',
    )

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('pos_order_ids.amount_total')
    def _compute_pos_order_total(self):
        for partner in self:
            total = 0.0
            for order in partner.pos_order_ids:
                total += order.amount_total
            partner.pos_order_total = total
```

Answer (score 1):

This another way solution:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    pos_order_total = fields.Float(
        string='POS Order Total',
        compute='_compute_pos_order_total',
        store=True)

    pos_order_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='pos.order',
                                    inverse_name='partner_id',
                                    string='Pos Ordres')


    @api.one
    @api.depends('pos_order_ids')
    def _compute_pos_order_total(self):

        Order_id = self.env['pos.order'].search([('partner_id', '=', self.id)])

        for Order in Order_id:
            total = 0.0
            total += Order.amount_total
        self.pos_order_total = total
```